# JQuery combine $(document).ready and $('DropDown').change declaration

Tags: jquery

I would like to run a function, `function myFunction()`, on the event `$(document).ready` *and* if a certain drop down changes, `$('#myDropDown').change`. Is there a good way to combine this declaration so I don't have two separate calls to `myFunction()`?

Currently I have the following -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //NOTE: I have other code in here that also needs to be called on $(document).ready

    myFunction();  // <--- I would like to get rid of one of the myFunction() calls

    $('#myDropDown').change(function() {

        myFunction();  //<---

    });

};
```

Comment: You could trigger the `change` event on the dropdown right after registering your handler, but this may have side effects (other handlers may also run). Better to call the function twice if you want full control of what happens.

Comment: You have to do something else in the change event or just call myFunction() ?

Comment: I just have to call myFunction(), aka Edward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('#myDropDown').on('change', myFunction).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Awesome answer, adeneo!

Answer (score 0):

you have to write 2 calls fo this function. A good way to do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //NOTE: I have other code in here that also needs to be called on $(document).ready

    myFunction();  // <--- I would like to get rid of one of the myFunction() calls

    $('#myDropDown').change(myFunction);

});
```